# What are registry and defined under require.s.contexts._?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

What are exactly `require.s.contexts._.defined` and `require.s.contexts._.registry` ?

Are modules in the `registry` object defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require.s.contexts` contains private data regarding all contexts that RequireJS knows about. The default context if you do not use the `context` configuration option is called `_` so `require.s.contexts._` contains private data regarding the default context.

The `registry` field of the context data contains a map that hold module information **temporarily**. A module will be in that map after it has been requested but only until it has been loaded.

The `defined` field contains a map of all modules defined in the context. You could conceivably access it directly but there's no clear reason to do this since `require.defined(id)` will tell you whether the module named by `id` is defined in the context to which `require` belongs. (Different contexts get different instances of `require` so a `require` function knows which context it originated from.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is a module defined once the `define` function as been called for this module or only when the `require` function has been called with this module as a dependency ?

Comment: It is defined once the callback to the `define` function has been run. So it has to have been required (directly or indirectly) before it is defined.

Comment: Thank your for your answers !